# Connect to remote database using Localhost install

Tags: database, localhost, xampp

I will be designing and developing a website for a client but want to allow the client to add content while I am working on the design and development of the site so that it is pretty mich done by the time I am finished.

Currently, I use XAMPP on port 81 so my project URL looks something like

```
http://localhost:81/projectname
```

My wp-config file has all the settings I need to the remote DB and yet, when I run the

```
http://localhost:81/projectname
```

URL it constantly redirects me to

```
http://localhost/projectname.
```

I've removed all htaccess files thinking the problem was there but that didn't work. My ISP suggested opening port 3306 which I have done but that's not done the trick either.

I don't know if it has to do with port 81 on Xampp perhaps?

**EDIT:**
General settings link through to the online version of the site so

Site Address = http://example.com

WP Address = http://example.com

Many thanks

Comment: What are your URL settings in Settings->General?

Comment: Try to check your apache configuration file also in your Xampp installation. You can check on this link how to setup multiple sites using xampp, which can help you test if the problem is Xampp: http://kuppalli.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/setup-multiple-sites-on-your-local-machine-using-xampp-or-apache-2/

Comment: I've made an edit to the above question shadum, thanks

Comment: Sorry? Your configuration settings link to an external site? That isn't ever going to work correctly. I am very confused by what you are doing now.

Comment: Thanks Camilo. I tried this thinking that adding port 3306 might do the trick but it didn't. I'm not having a problem with multiple projects but rather, a problem running a local project that connects to a remote DB.

Comment: Is there no way to pull the content to a localhost site just to get the content onto the site so that I can work on the development of the site while the client adds the content to the live DB? I've not done this in WP before but we have managed to do this with DNN many years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think s_ha_dum is in the right track, but I think he got it backwards.

You want to:

1. develop/design locally
2. connect to the REMOTE database and work with his content?

You need a remote (staging) installation of WordPress, where the client can create/enter his content.

You need your local WordPress site (localhost) to point to the remote database, to grab the content he is using.

So, you would have your http://example.com/wordpress set up for the client to edit - just even with a vanilla WP install. This site would be connected to it's own database.

Your localhost site would have the REMOTE site's database credentials, with the `DB_HOST` set to http://example.com, or whatever the mySQL path is if it's accessed another way through your hosting provider.

On your local site, keep the `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` set to localhost. Otherwise, you'll get redirection loops.

Comment: Thanks Eric that is what's been happening and what you are suggesting is what I would like to achieve but I kept getting the redirect problem.

I will combine both of your solutions and get back to you :) Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, it's `WP_SITEURL`, not `WP_SITE_URL`. If that doesn't work, you may need to define `define('WP_RELOCATE', true);` in your `wp-config.php` file, log in, then remove the line.

Comment: Thanks Eric, not had time to spend on it again but I will as soon as I get a moment.

Comment: Hi Eric. On a new project now and tested this. It works super well but really slow. Is there a way to speed it up perhaps?

Comment: You only need the relocate definition for the first log-in when transferring a website. Remove it once it's working properly. :)

Comment: Not quite following? What I meant is that everything is working  but the connection from Localhost to load pages is quite slow. Is there some way to speed this up? I have tried the URL as well as the IP address to the DB but both options have been slow.

Comment: Yes, remove `define('WP_RELOCATE', true);` from your `wp-config.php` file.

Comment: Add a foot note here, when I first using remote database before using the `WP_SITEURL and `WP_HOME`, it did not have any redirection problem. It just load the remote set of php styles also but with some files cannot be loaded because of CORS warning. After changing the config, it works immediately also.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there no way to pull the content to a localhost site just to get
>   the content onto the site so that I can work on the development of the
>   site while the client adds the content to the live DB?

If the remote server supports it, you can connect to the remote database. Just [set your connection constants correctly](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Default_wp-config-sample.php):

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'database_name_here' );

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'username_here' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here' );

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
```

You will almost certainly also have to [set these on the local install](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29):

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/wordpress' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/wordpress' );
```

I can almost guarantee that you are still going to have issues, not to mention that changes *you* make are to the live server.

There are other potential solutions, like database mirroring, but that would be off-topic here and I've never done it.

My advice is to just copy the live database to your local server at the project start and ***do not*** try to sync the databases or otherwise connect the development site with the live one. You are asking for trouble. WordPress does not have a sharp content/config separation in the database.

Comment: Thanks Shadum, I might go that route of constantly grabbing a new version of the live DB...and don't worry, the live DB is hidden behind a URL until the actual site goes live :)

Comment: Nope, didn't work. Thanks for the effort though Shadum

Comment: My advice is the last paragraph, please note.

Comment: Thanks Shadum...will go this route on your last paragraph

Comment: @SixfootJames : you accepted this answer long ago, but have now unaccepted it and have not accepted an alternative. Why?

Comment: Hi Shadum, I went through all these options and tried it again but it didn't work so I am hoping someone else might have a solution.

Comment: @SixfootJames : you are probably going to have to provide more detail.

Comment: We used to do this with DNN at the previous place I worked at. The team could be working on different parts of a website project while the owner of the site starts writing their content directly into the CMS. So every person has a copy of the site via SVN but everyone makes a connection to one database which speeds up the development process. So, I would like to achieve the same thing with WordPress. The only alternative would be to host my own internal server and then with the use of NO-IP, give the client access to the site that is connected through my own network?

Comment: I have also connected to remote databases, but doing so depends on server configuration, which might be your problem. Not all servers allow remote connections.

Comment: Shadum, I actually called my ISP just the other day and they assured me that it is possible. If I gave you the remote database's details, do you think you could show me how to make that connection in a config file please? I tried all the settings you gave me above and when I navigate from my localhost file for example, and then click on another page, I am taken to the live site's page, rather than remaining on the localhost pages.

Comment: Your ISP? Do you mean your web host?

Comment: Yes, sorry, we call it an Internet Service Provider here :)